# The procedure entry point CryptAcquireContextA could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\myexe.exe

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, crypto++

I compiled a program with Crypto++ and boost when I try to start it I get the error message below. `CryptAcquireContextA` is used by Crypto++ and boost.

```
The procedure entry point CryptAcquireContextA could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\myexe.exe
```

The `CryptAcquireContextA` function is in the `Advapi32.dll` which I already tried copying next to my .exe. I tried linking against `-ladvapi32` but that also didn't work.

I compiled Crypto++ and boost with i686-mingw-w64 under Ubuntu.

Here is a screenshot of the exact error I'm getting:

[image: image1]

And here is a screenshot of dependency walker:

[image: image2]

The CryptAcquireContextA is in the ADVAPI32.DLL and is used by cryptopp.
I have the WINFSP-X64.DLL next to the executable and it is not complaining about that one.

I also tried compiling it with x86_x64-mingw-w64 that's why I'm using the x64 dll of WinFsp.

I just noticed WinFsp is also using `CryptAcquireContextA` so the issue may be in WinFsp. Maybe it is not compatible with mingw?

Comment: "but that also didn't work" - what happened instead?

Comment: @sehe Same error as in the title. Nothing changed...

Comment: What happens if you build the program with `-static`?

Are you actually running the program on Windows, or was this using Wine?

Comment: @BrechtSanders I'm running my program in a Windows 10 VM using VirtualBox. I tried compiling with `-static`. I now no longer need any additional dll's but the error still occurs.

Comment: @Gary Can you post the exact error you get and when exactly you get it? Also, can you examine your .exe with Dependancy Walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which DLLs it's still depending on?

Comment: @BrechtSanders I added it to the Question.

Comment: @Gary I have tried to build WinFsp with MinGW in the past but was never successful.
If you're using a prebuilt shared library from WinFsp it makes sense that that would add dependancies to your file

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the screenshot of the whole Dependency Walker window, but from what I can see you're mixing a win64 exe with win32 DLLs.

Wasn't Dependency Walker telling you this when opening the .exe file?